# Share data between components in other files

Tags: typescript, angular, bind

I want to share data from a component to an other component in an other file. I've created an array of objects/Classes and i want to delete them after clicking the delete button. In this file is the data created:

```
@Component({
selector: 'condition-builder',
templateUrl: 'app/conditionbuilder.component.html',
providers: [ConditionService],
directives: [ConditionDetailComponent]
})

export class ConditionBuilderComponent implements OnInit {
    conditions: Condition[] = [];
    catalog: Condition[] = [];

constructor(private _conditionService: ConditionService) { }

getConditions() {
    this._conditionService.getConditions().then(conditions => this.catalog = conditions);
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.getConditions();
}

onChange(conditionsIndex, catalogIndex) {
    //console.log(selectedCondition);
    //console.log(conditionsIndex);
    console.log(catalogIndex);
    this.conditions[conditionsIndex] = this.catalog[catalogIndex];
}

newCondition() {
    this.conditions.push(this.catalog[0]);
}

deleteCondition() {
    this.conditions.pop();
}
}
```

and i want to access the condition data or the method deleteCondition(); in this file:

```
export class SelectCondition extends Condition {
public name: string = 'select';
public fileValue: string;
public selectedOperator: string = 'in';

public selectOperators: Condition[] = [
    "in"
];

selectFile() {
    $(document).on('change', '.btn-file :file', function() {
        var input = $(this),
            numFiles = input.get(0).files ? input.get(0).files.length : 1,
            label = input.val().replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '');
        input.trigger('fileselect', [numFiles, label]);
    });

    $('.btn-file :file').on('fileselect', function(event, numFiles, label) {
        var input = $(this).parents('.input-group').find(':text'),
            log = numFiles > 1 ? numFiles + ' files selected' : label;

        if( input.length ) {
            input.val(log);

            console.log(input.val());
        }
    });
}

deleteCondition() {
    console.log('check');
    conditions.pop();
}
}
```

How do i acces the data from the current condition and delete it. To make it clear here are some screenshots:

First it was like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/92z2oe7f4w5x2b5/conditions.jpg?dl=0 Here it deletes the last created.

but i want to delete each condition separately like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ptwq6sk6da4p21k/new.jpg?dl=0

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the service provider when bootstrapping your application:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ConditionService]);
```

This way you will share the same instance of your service accross the whole application when injecting it.

Be careful to remove the service from any `providers` attribute of your components.

You can also inject your service into your `SelectCondition` service:

```
@Injectable()
export class SelectCondition extends Condition {
  constructor(private service: ConditionService) {
  }

  deleteCondition() {
    console.log('check');
    service.conditions.pop();
  }
}
```

Don't forget to also add this service when bootstrapping your application:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ConditionService, SelectCondition]);
```

Comment: I get an error message: Error: Cannot read property 'getOptional' of undefined(…)


Here is a plunker not working but you can see the file structure:
http://plnkr.co/edit/WRSbdQkla3uQlW3HLxQd?p=preview

Comment: Don't forget to remove the providers from `ConditionBuilderComponent`

Comment: after adding SelectCondition to bootstrap(ConditionBuilderComponent, [ConditionService, SelectCondition]);

Comment: You shouldn't have both `@Injectable` and `@Component` on the `SelectCondition`. It's either a component or a service. Perhaps you could create a new class (service) and move corresponding processing to this class...

Comment: Sorry but i do not know what you mean.. I need to make a new file with a new service class and put the code you wrote in it? 

Excuse me for my stupidity

Comment: I need selectcondition to be a component

Comment: do you have an example?

Comment: I did something like this now : 
export function deleteCondition() {
    this.conditions.pop();
}

But when i run that method in the other file it will not recognise .pop() how can i delete that row out of my array?